How Layout Composable's measure policy measure its child using parent constraints?
I am trying to make a custom layout to understand how it works and place and measure its child composables. If I set the size of my custom composable and then measure the child in the Layout's measure scope the child is being forced to have width and height equals to the parent's max width and height:
@Composable
fun CustomComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content,
        measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
            val placeables = measurables.map {
                it.measure(constraints)
            }

            layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
                var y = 0
                placeables.forEach {
                    it.place(0, y)
                    y += (it.height)
                }
            }
        },
    )
}

I am using it like this:
CustomComposable(
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(200.dp)
        .background(color = Color.Red)
) {
    Text(text = "Text 1", modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp))
    Text(text = "Text 2", modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp))
}

Output of above code:

When I don't set a size then the children are laid out according to the width and height they need but the parent is laid out full screen:
CustomComposable(
    modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color.Red)
) {
    Text(text = "Text 1")
    Text(text = "Text 2")
}

When no size is set for the parent:

I want to understand this behavior (why is it happening, How can I achieve the parent respects its constraints and if I set the size of the child it is being respected and if not then it's taking as much space as it needs, until and unless it's told to match its parent like in the example below) and how it's being handled in other composables? Like this Column:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(color = Color.Red)
) {
    Text(text = "this is 1", modifier = Modifier.size(20.dp))
    Text(text = "this is 2")
}

How to do something like in these images:

Left: Column with its own size as fill max width and its size has its own size
Right: column with no size given but child with its own size



One final question: If we pass a size to CustomComposable and changed its width and height in layout(newWidth, newHeight) {}, will the layout's dimensions changes? If not then is there a point of manually calculating it? As when ever somebody is sending it the mentioned size will be set only.

I think IntrinsicSize can help here
for example if you set modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Max) that the composable will only take as mush space as its widest child, and not more than that
